# Цикл while внутри еще 1 цикл

Tags: php, mysql

Ломаю голову уже 3 день, перепробовал все (LEFT JOIN и тд.).

Суть есть цикл while, который выводит все данные из mysql из таблицы zvonki. В итоге все отображается в формате таблицы, как и нужно. Каждую ячейку я могу отредактировать с помощью x-editable.

Вопрос вот в чем, есть таблица napravlenie, в этой таблице есть перечень допустимых значений. То есть в 1 ячейку я хочу запретить добавлять хаотичные значения, поэтому в таблице napravlenie я внес допустимые значения. При добавление записи в таблицу все работает отлично, циклом while я вывожу все значения в select/option. Но мне надо, чтобы и при редактирование он выдавал значения только из таблицы napravlenie.

В итоге моя логика выглядит так:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM zvonki ORDER BY id DESC')
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM napravlenie")

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
...
    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) ){
    ....
    }
...
}
```

Цикл прерывается когда доходит до 2 цикла

Comment: В итоге цикл выполняется и прерывается на 2 цикле.

Comment: `mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM napravlenie");` будет выбирать __одно и то же__. Нет абсолютно никакого смысла делать это в цикле.

Comment: А проблема ваша в том что вы переменную `$result` __переопределяете__.

Comment: Нет абсолютно никакого смысла делать это в цикле - не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду. Думаю, Вы не правильно поняли задумку.

Comment: А проблема ваша в том что вы переменную $result переопределяете - дело не в этом, так как здесь я накидал на скорую руку, до этого все переменные везде были уникальные, тобишь во 2 цикле была переменная не $result, а $result2.

Comment: Вот вместо того чтобы накидывать код на скорую руку и создавать ошибки которых нет, привели бы __реальный код__, который работает не так как надо.

Comment: Исправил стартовый пост, чтобы не вводить вас в заблуждение

Comment: На скорую руку, потому что я убирал 2 цикл и пытался вынести параметр id из ссылки в модальное окно (то есть вынести за цикл и зациклить уже после 1 цикла), но у меня не получилось. Поэтому для этого поста пришлось все возвращать на место, примерно как было. Соответственно небольшие ошибки появились.

Comment: result2 можно fetch только один раз. на второй итерации внешнего цикла вы все записи из него уже выбрали и второй раз их не получите. Вынесите внутренний цикл и поставьте его перед первым. Данные получаемые им сохраните в массив. И когда будете работать с zvonki, то пользуйтесь готовым массивом, вместо fetch. Кроме того, если я вас правильно понял и на основе данных из napravlenie строится какой то <select> то строку `<option>..<option>` для него можно так же построить один раз перед основным циклом в текстовой переменной и уже готовую печатать там где надо

Comment: Так же для упрощения можно вообще не делать цикл чтения napravlenie а воспользоваться функцией mysqli_fetch_all() которая даст готовый массив строк с которым уже дальше можно работать по своему усмотрению

Comment: Спасибо, сохранил все в массив $existing_users[], $existing_users[1] - выводит 1 значение. Как мне теперь вывести цикл? Foreach? <option value="<? echo $existing_users[1]; ?>"><? echo $existing_users[1]; ?></option> Далее 2 элемент и тд, чтобы все элементы вывело.

Comment: Перебрал все циклом for. Всем спасибо за помощь))